# SLI with Gigabyte GeForce RTX 2080 Gaming OC 8G

Tags: graphics-cards

I have a 34x14 monitor so I want to SLI for games. I have an i7 8700 3.7 on a good motherboard.

I've been told my card won't work with new cards. It's a

Gigabyte GeForce RTX 2080 Gaming OC 8G

This only matches used cards? What's the issue?

I should just get two new 2080s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Support page](https://www.gigabyte.com/Graphics-Card/GV-N2080GAMING-8GC#kf) shows that it supports SLI, but you need to pair your card with an identical one. If you have the original 2080, not the Ti or Super variants, then you need to find an original card. This can be hard to do as they have mostly phased the original out in favor of the Super, but that doesn't make it impossible.

Comment: What's the difference between the two? They're just built to not work together?

Comment: The Super has 128 more Cuda cores and faster memory.